# Applying numpy array of functions to a single input

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ufunc

I'm trying to achieve something of this sort:

```
f1 = lambda x: x**2
f2 = lambda x: x**3
fn = np.array([f1, f2])
print(fn(3))
```

So that it returns an array with the outputs in place. Of course, I could do it like this:

```
result = np.array([f(x) for f in fn])
```

But this seems like an inefficient way to do it... especially if there are a lot of such functions.

Is there an alternative to this? Something more efficient; maybe like *numpy ufuncs*? I do not know how to do the implementation.

Comment: The fast efficient numpy code works primarily with numeric dtypes.  Your `fn` is object dtype.  There is little, if any, advantage to using such an array instead of a list.

Comment: @hpaulj So, I should just stick to the way I'm doing it, or could there be a better method?